# Parsing pairs of braces containing brace escapes

Tags: text-processing, text, text-formatting

I have some text where certain parts are marked with `_{...}`; I need to replace the enclosing underscore and brace pair with asterisks. So, for example, `Hello _{world} _{foo}` would become `Hello *world* *foo*`.

This is an easy problem, which could be easily solved with `sed -r 's/_\{([^}]+)}/*\1*/g'`, were it not for the fact that they can contain brace escapes. So, for example, the text:

```
Hello _{world \} \}} _{foo bar}
```

would result in:

```
Hello *world } }* *foo bar*
```

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Can backslashes also be used to escape more backslashes?  If your input contains `_{world \\}`, should that `}` be replaced or not?

Comment: @JigglyNaga No, backslashes are just for escaping `}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a backslash means "escape the next character" (whether it's a brace, another backslash, or anything except end-of-line), then you can "skip" that next character like this:

```
sed -r 's/_\{((\\.|[^}\\])+)\}/*\1*/g
```

If backslash only has a special meaning before a brace, then you need to "skip" the first non-backslash character after every run of 1 or more backslashes:

```
sed -r 's/_\{((\\+[^\]|[^}\\])+)\}/*\1*/g'
```

Comment: `hello _{world \} \} \} foo bar` gets converted as `hello *world \} \} \* foo bar` with both approaches.

Comment: @user2064000 This approach is the correct one. Just add backslash into the negated character class `[^}]`.

Comment: @icarus Thanks, I didn't test that carefully enough.  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to match something not preceded by something, you need a negative look-behind. `sed` doesn't support look-ahead and look-behind, but Perl does.

```
echo 'Hello _{world \} \}} _{foo bar}' | perl -npe 's/_\{(.+?)(?<!\\)}/*\1*/g'
```

This will output:

> ```
> Hello *world \} \}* *foo bar*
> ```

Comment: Can't you just use `/[^\]}/` to match "anything not a backslash followed by a closed curly-brace" in `sed` (notwithstanding escaping)?

Comment: @DopeGhoti, no, because unlike the negative lookbehind, the `[^\]` would end up consuming some other character if '\' isn't there. Lookarounds don't consume any characters.

Comment: What about a Passive Group, which doesn't consume what it "matches"?  Though I imagine that's even less likely to be supported in `sed`, now that I ruminate upon it.

Comment: @DopeGhoti A non-capturing group does consume the string; it simply does not make it available through the backreference mechanism.